# GLM - rotation makes objects disappear

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation, glm-math

I'm doing the rotation on two objects in OpenGL. one which works:

```
        Model1 = glm::translate( ... );
        Model1 = glm::scale( ... );
        Model1 = glm::rotate(Model1, 90 , glm::vec3(1,0,0));
```

and one which doesnt:

```
        Model2 = glm::translate( ... );
        Model2 = glm::scale( ... );
        Model2 = glm::rotate(Model2, 90 , glm::vec3(0,0,0));
```

which makes my Object disappear.

I assume this is caused due to multiplication by 0 (or sth similar).
Then, how should I represent No rotation?

Is axis-angle a good way of using rotations, or one should store them as quaternions and use a different function or convert back to angle-axis each time Rotation is being applied?

Comment: Why don't you remove the line "Model2 = glm::rotate(Model2, 90 , glm::vec3(0,0,0));"?

Comment: Cause I'm doing it in the loop on **n** objects, and I want to apply Rotation each time, even if  it's rotation is like `glm::rotate(Model2, 90 , glm::vec3(0,0,0));` (objects are rotatable and I'd have to check each time if there's no such a disappearing case)

Answer (score 4):

> Then, how should I represent No rotation?

By an angle of 0 (instead of 90). Not by degenerating the rotation axis.